# Adding Map Key to map or console in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there a way to print (or plot) a map key in the console (or on the map) in google earth engine ? What would be an approach?

```js
var img= ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2....................');
var ndvi = im.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
var ndvi_brg = {min:-1, max: 1, palette: ['blue','#8B0000','green']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(rect), ndvi_brg, 'ndvi',true);
```

I'm ploting an NDVI in a specific area and would like to print the map key for the color palette 'ndvi_brg' as a visual clue
(Like something in the following picture:)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The annotation capabilties of Earth Engine are currently pretty limited, but you can fake a colorbar with something like this:

```
function ColorBar(palette) {
  return ui.Thumbnail({
    image: ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select(0),
    params: {
      bbox: [0, 0, 1, 0.1],
      dimensions: '200x20',
      format: 'png',
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      palette: palette,
    },
    style: {stretch: 'horizontal', margin: '0px 8px'},
  });
}

function makeLegend(low, mid, high, palette) {
  var labelPanel = ui.Panel(
      [
        ui.Label(low, {margin: '4px 8px'}),
        ui.Label(mid, {margin: '4px 8px', textAlign: 'center', stretch: 'horizontal'}),
        ui.Label(high, {margin: '4px 8px'})
      ],
      ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'));
  return ui.Panel([ColorBar(palette), labelPanel])
}

Map.add(makeLegend(-1, 0, 1, ["yellow", "orange", "green", "white"]))
```

[image]